# Probability of Two Things Happening?

Tags: probability

So I have been learning basic probability of single events happening, but there is a bonus question asking how to get the probability of two events happening, and I have absolutely no idea how to do that. What is the formula for doing so, and how would you go about setting that up?

Marciano draws five cards from a 52-card deck.  Calculate the probability of each given event.

Two cards are sevens, given there are no face cards

Answer (score 0):

Try and think of a way to systematically create all possible hands with exactly two sevens. Figure out how many hands that creates. Respond with thoughts in comments under my answer.

Now find the total number of five-card hands (out of a deck with face cards removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider that he is drawing from a $40$ card deck, a standard deck that has the face cards removed.  What is the chance he gets two sevens?

Answer (score 0):

There are $12$ face cards in a deck (four suits of K,J,Q ... unless you count A).

Given that none of those have been drawn, Marciano has drawn 5 cards from the remaining 40; and further, all outcomes of *this* space are equally probable.

Find the probability that Marciano has drawn 2,3, or all 4 from the sevens (*at least* 2) from this space; or equally *not* drawn only 0, or 1 from the sevens.

> $$\mathbb P(\text{sevens}{=}2\mid\text{faces}{=}0) ~=~ 1 - \frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{36}{\bf 5}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{36}{\bf 4}}{\binom{40}{{\bf 5}}}$$

Comment: Wouldnt it be 40/5 on the bottom, or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: @Steberz tyop,  thank you,

Comment: I end up with 0.02. Then if I do 1-0.02 its 0.98, which is definitely not right. What am I doing wrong?